# Default class naming customization in Eclipse using CDT

Tags: eclipse, configuration, eclipse-plugin, customization, eclipse-cdt

When I try to create a new class in Eclipse using the CDT plugin I enter in the name of the class.  For example MyClass.  This generates the default file names MyClass.h and MyClass.cpp.  I want to change the default file naming to be of the form my_class.h and my_class.cc.  Can this modification be made and if so can it be done from within Eclipse?  Does this setting reside in a configuration file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature currently doesn't exist in Eclipse Helios (3.6) CDT.  I found a request for the feature in the [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=138598), but it was requested back in 2006, has had very little activity, and isn't even currently assigned to anyone.  Sadly, I don't think customization of C++ class filenames isgoing to be added to Eclipse anytime soon.